# Alert before remove items select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I don't know how to make a condition that will show alert when someone want will remove items from select2.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#select_name").select2({
            multiple: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 2,
            minimumInputLength: 2,
        }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
            $(this).val([]).trigger('change');
            $(this).val([e.params.data.id]).trigger("change");      
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here my friend. you just need to return false, if you don't want to remove the item and return true if you want.

Select2 - Events: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example').select2({
       multiple: true,
       maximumSelectionLength: 2,
       minimumInputLength: 2,
    }).on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
         alert('Opps. Removing item?')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="example" style="width: 100px;" name="state">
  <option value="one">Example 1</option>
  <option value="two">Example 2</option>
  <option value="three">Example 3</option>
</select>
```